# What is known about the cohomology of the matrix monoid?

Tags: reference-request, cohomology, semigroups-and-monoids

When I say the cohomology of a monoid, I mean that of its classifying space (considering the monoid as a category with a single object).

Let $M_n(R)$ be the monoid of matrices with matrix multiplication over some (commutative) ring $R$, sometimes called the full linear monoid. Is there any literature about the cohomology of $M_n(R)$ for certain classes (say, finite fields) of $R$?

I thought there should be at least something out there, considering the attention the general linear group gets. But I can't find anything. Perhaps I am not searching with the right keywords.

Comment: The classifying space is contractible: there exists an element $0$ such that $0A=0=A0$, which allows you to construct a homotopy between the identity map of the classifying space and a constant map.

Comment: Ah, sure. (Fulfilling the character quota with humility)

Comment: You would probably do better looking at the Hochschild-Mitchell cohomology.